# Pandas - drop rows that all values is a specific string

Tags: pandas, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have a `_df` variable set-up as the following:

```
In [41]: _df
Out[41]: 
                                    0                                  1
0   validated_name1_conf66.67_err0.00  validated_name2_conf66.67_err0.00
1                                   -                                  -
2                                   -                                  -
3                                  Name                            Name2
4                                 XYZ                                ABC
5                                 XYZ                                ABC
6                                   -                                  -
7                                   -                                  -
8                                   -                                  -
9                                   -                                  -
10                                  -                                  -
11
```

I'd like to remove rows that all its values are a specific `string`, in this example, the specific string is `-` character.

**I can achieve what I want to achieve** through the following method chaining, which I think is extremely inefficient

```
In [42]: (
    ...:  _df
    ...:  .T
    ...:  .replace('-', np.nan)
    ...:  .dropna(axis=1)
    ...:  .T
    ...: )
Out[42]: 
                                   0                                  1
0  validated_name1_conf66.67_err0.00  validated_name2_conf66.67_err0.00
3                                 Name                            Name2
4                                XYZ                                ABC
5                                XYZ                                ABC
```

In the method chaining above, I'm transposing the axis using `.T` and then utilize `.replace` method to replace all `-` string into `np.nan` values and drop them afterwards using `dropna()` and finally transpose it back with `.T`.

I tried to use a more straightforward way such as the result below:

```
In [43]: _df[_df.values != '-']
Out[43]: 
                                   0                                  1
0  validated_name1_conf66.67_err0.00  validated_name2_conf66.67_err0.00
0  validated_name1_conf66.67_err0.00  validated_name2_conf66.67_err0.00
3                                 Name                            Name2
3                                 Name                            Name2
4                                XYZ                                ABC
4                                XYZ                                ABC
5                                XYZ                                ABC
5                                XYZ                                ABC
```

I am aware of iterating over columns method, but in my case, it won't perfectly suit what I would like to achieve.

### Question

Is there a more efficient way to achieve what I want to achieve instead of using the method chaining I used on the code second from the top?

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve? your formatting seems "different" and it's not in clear text

Comment: The values in the Index 3~5 might confuse everyone. It is actually a preprocessed data that was taken and produced with `header=None` arguments. What I want to achieve actually is just to remove rows that all the values is a particular string, in this case it is `'-'` string. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I already found a solution:

```
In [ ]: _df[_df.values != '-'].drop_duplicates()
Out[ ]: 
                                   0                                  1
0  validated_name1_conf66.67_err0.00  validated_name2_conf66.67_err0.00
3                                Name                               Name2
4                                XYZ                                ABC
5                                XYZ                                ABC
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to handle this problem since the data goes beyond 100k~ish rows.
Suggestions will be appreciated!